# numpy.atleast(), RamdonForestClassifier and numpy.hstack functions

Tags: numpy

I have this doubt about what is the exactly way of working of numpy.atleast(), RamdonForestClassifier and numpy.hstack functions.

I've read documentation about the purpose of all of those functions I mention above, but it is still not clear.
Can someone please help me?!

The method I am dealing with is the one below:

```py
     def fit(self, X, Y):
                 X, Y = map(np.atleast_2d, (X, Y))
                 assert X.shape[0] == Y.shape[0]
                 Ny = Y.shape[1]
                 
                 self.clfs = []
                 for i in range(Ny):
                     clf = RandomForestClassifier(*self.args, **self.kwargs,n_jobs=-1)
                     Xi = np.hstack([X, Y[:, :i]])
                     yi = Y[:, i]
                     self.clfs.append(clf.fit(Xi, yi))
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are asking

Comment: In few words, what that method  "fit" is doing.
I am new to Machine Learning, including the libraries of Pandas - Numpy and I am currently learning the way of working of  different functions coming form those libraries. That is the reason I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so let me explain step by step.

So, `np.atleast_2d()` converts any input to a 2D array.

```
np.atleast_2d(1)
Out[5]: array([[1]])

np.atleast_2d([1,2])
Out[6]: array([[1, 2]])
```

So, as you can see it is converting them to a 2D array, similarly in your code,
`X, Y = map(np.atleast_2d, (X, Y))`, this maps the function `np.atleast_2d` to these inputs X and Y such that given inputs X, Y, it will convert them to to 2-D arrays.

Next, regarding `RandomForestClassifier`
`clf = RandomForestClassifier(*self.args, **self.kwargs,n_jobs=-1)` line initializes the model or the classifier for you.

```
a = np.arange(0,4,1).reshape(2,2)
Y = np.arange(5,9,1).reshape(2,2)
res = np.hstack([a,Y])
res
Out[10]: 
array([[0, 1, 5, 6],
       [2, 3, 7, 8]])
res.shape
Out[11]: (2, 4)
```

See 2 rows and 4 columns
`np.hstack` just horizontally stacks the input arrays.
`Xi = np.hstack([X, Y[:, :i]])`, this line basically stacks the inputs X with the probable labels.
`clf.fit(Xi, yi)`, this function fits the data to your model. Its like I initialized a black box or a system and now I am passing the data into that system to train the system to adapt to that data. Feel free to ask if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Great explanation.
It is only that It is not pretty clear for me on the Y[:, :i] (2nd argument of hstack function).
Xi = np.hstack([X, **Y[:, :i]**])
Why is that part written in that way?

Comment: Your welcome. So, I would recommend reading up on ML and getting familiar with numpy library. This [exercise](https://github.com/rougier/numpy-100) is very helpful